# Change the Layout Background using image color code in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am using the `viewPager` for `Gallery` and used `"Depth Page Transformation"` for `animation` i need to set the `background` according to the `image`. The `background color` should match with the `image` color meaning it should pick the `background color` from the `image`. Does any one know this..please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the pixel's color data and average the color values, ignore anything that is a shade of grey or transparent. I believe that is what Microsoft does in Windows 7 based on a recent blog post.

See this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/06/10244432.aspx

This link showing how Chrome picks the dominant color may also be helpful.   http://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/How-does-Chrome-pick-the-color-for-the-stripes-on-the-Most-visited-page-thumbnails

Find this snippet for android
http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/android-development/406-%5Bhow-%5D-get-average-color-drawable-bitmap.html